# continually getting a parameter box "error" when I use an SQL query to grab a value?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to create a button inside of a Microsoft Access 2016 database for inventory tracking that, on click, displays an InputBox asking for the Serial Number, UDID, and/or IMEI of the device in question. I have an SQL query embedded in the private sub, code below:

```vb
Private Sub cmdInventoryItems_Click()
On Error Resume Next

Dim vItem As String
vItem = InputBox("Type the Serial Number/UDID/IMEI of your device.", "Text 
Search")

Dim StrSQL As String
StrSQL = "Select * from tbl_Inventory where [Serial Number/UDID/IMEI] like 
[%" & vItem & "%]"
Me.RecordSource = StrSQL

End Sub
```

The percentage signs inside the code are meant to allow the string to be compared to any piece of the Serial Number/UDID/IMEI field.

Whenever I click cmdInventoryItems it throws an InputBox, as planned, but when a value is input into the textbox, access asks for a parameter value with the prompt being the value I just entered surrounded by percentage symbols. If I type nothing into the "Enter parameter value" box everything disappears on my main form.

Can anyone explain what's going on, and how to fix it?
Thanks for any help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

Access expects square brackets to denote a field (or table) name or a parameter. If you tested with `somefield = [anything]` you will see a parameter box appearing containing the text `anything`.

Get rid of the square brackets and replace them with single quotes, which you need to surround a textual expression, `'%" & vItem & "%'"`.

However, the wildcard character for MS Access is an asterisk * not a percent sign.

Comment: Andy G, thank you for your help, you definitely got me one step further. However, the percentage symbols are meant to search the entire field for one that includes what you've typed. They aren't doing that even with my inclusion of the "like" operator:
    ' StrSQL = "Select * from tbl_Inventory where [Serial 
    Number/UDID/IMEI] like '%" & vItem & "%'" '
This code is fine is I want to do a one-to-one search (Which I'd do differently if that was the case) , but I want to search the fields for the string I type, even if there is a case difference and even if there are also numbers...

Comment: For MS Access the [wildcard character](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1) is an asterisk * not a percent sign.

Answer (score 0):

your code line: 
StrSQL = "Select * from tbl_Inventory where [Serial Number/UDID/IMEI] like 
[%" & vItem & "%]"

Q: is the field name of the table actually & exactly?: Serial Number/UDID/IMEI

the code line must be this:

StrSQL = "Select * from tbl_Inventory where [TableFieldName] like 
" * " & vItem & " * "  "

note there should be no spaces around the asterisks - but without them in this post they didn't seem to display correctly: "*" & vItem & "*""